# Minimum number of lines

Tags: combinations

We got 28 numbers and we write them in lines. Every line consists of  6 numbers. If we pick 5 numbers randomly from 28 numbers we wanna cover all posibble combinations of 3 numbers in minimum lines posbile. Example:
if we pick 4 5 12 16 22 we wanna have 4 5 12, 4 5 16, 4 5 22 ect. (10 combinations)
in one or more lines but gota have all combinations covered in minimum posible lines.

Comment: Interesting task! So, what did you try?

Comment: This question is for a different forum.  It’s off topic and should perhaps but in mathoverflow.

Comment: I don't think this question belongs to Stack OverFlow...

Comment: Didn't try. I'm not a programer. Trying to get answer to this problem but couldn't get anywhere on internet  so i tried here cos i heard i could maybe get an answer here.

Comment: @rookie123  Try the `mathematics` forum.

Comment: Tx for the help guys. I thought this wasn't for stackoverflow but maybe it is cos if we write a code for it we can just change 28 numbers every time to get lines with those numbers.